# model.avg returns error dim(x) must have a positive length. Code worked previously, but I change values of one parameter and it's broken

Tags: r, information-theory

I'm trying to plug a new parameter into some model averaging code that I've been using (problem free) for months, and I am now getting an error message that I've never seen before.

My code is as follows

```
library(MuMIn)
mod1<-lm(response ~ predictor1 + predictor2 + predictor3 + ... + predictor6, data=dataset)
cand.set<-dredge(mod1, beta=T, evaluate=T, m.max=6)
modavg_95<-model.avg(cand.set, cumsum(weight)<=.95)
```

That last line is where I get the following error message

```
Error in apply(apply(z, 2L, is.na),2,all):
dim(x) must have a positive length
```

This code worked fine before, and all I've done is change the values of predictor6. There are no NA values in the data, class(predictor6) returns numeric for both datasets, and the max min values of predictor6 are still within the range they were in before.

My code is identical. What does this error mean, why am I getting it, and how can I go about fixing it?

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much in advance.

========================

**Edit:** It was suggested that I run `traceback()` to see which calling function is throwing the error. I've never used this function before, but this is what is returned when I run it:

```
8: stop("dim(X) must have a positive length")
7: apply(apply(z, 2L, is.na), 2, all)
6: `[.data.frame`(z, , !apply(apply(z, 2L, is.na), 2, all) & !(tt %in% 
       attr(tt, "interceptLabel")), drop = FALSE)
5: z[, !apply(apply(z, 2L, is.na), 2, all) & !(tt %in% attr(tt, 
       "interceptLabel")), drop = FALSE]
4: importance.model.selection(object)
3: importance(object)
2: model.avg.model.selection(cand.set, cumsum(weight) <= 0.95)
1: model.avg(cand.set, cumsum(weight) <= 0.95)
```

Comment: Have you used either `browser()` or `traceback()` to see which calling function is throwing this error?

Comment: This error occurs if there is only one model, so nothing to average. Make sure your `subset(cand.set, cumsum(weight)<=.95))` has at least two rows.

Comment: @KamilBartoń My candidate set currently has 64 rows

Comment: @BondedDust I've never run `traceback()` before, and am not sure how to interpret it's output, but I've added what it returns to the main body of my question.

Comment: @melanopygus: `can.set` may have 64 rows, but you're taking a subset of it with `cumsum(weight)<=.95)`, so I suppose this subset has only one row. Update **MuMIn** to the latest version from R-Forge (`install.packages("MuMIn", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org"`). It now should give a more meaningful error message if only one row table is provided.